# Interface in an array

Tags: c#, arrays, design-patterns, interface

Hye everyone,
Do you know if it is good practice to make a table with an interface like this? :

```
 public interface ITemp
 {
    void Findpath();
 }

 public class TempUn : ITemp
 {
    public void Findpath()
    {
          throw new System.NotImplementedException();
    }
 }

 public class TempDeux : ITemp
 {
     public int deux;
     public void Findpath()
     {
          throw new System.NotImplementedException();
     }
 }

 public ITemp[] TabTest;

 public void init()
 {
     var un = new TempUn();
     var deux = new TempDeux();

     TabEssai = new ITemp[2];
        TabEssai[0] = un;
        TabEssai[1] = deux;
 }
```

I'm asking this because if I understand correctly the creation of the array allocates a fixed memory. I'm not sure if it's a good idea to create an array of elements that respect the interface but are of variable size, , is that a problem?

Good Day,

Comment: It's not a problem.  The array will store references to your objects, which will reside on the heap.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking having a public method or property returning an array is not an issue. In c# array does store objects themselves, but only pointers to these objects on the heap. The fact that your array is of type `ITemp` only means that you're strong-typing your array to those classes that implement this interface. And nothing more. It could of been `object[]` in a worse scenario.

Examples of public APIs that return arrays - in .NET framework you have many `reflection` and `IO` methods that return arrays - `GetFiles()`, `GetMethods()` etc.

In this case, because this is not an arbitrary number of similar objects I would return some type

```
public class SomeUnit
{
    public ITemp TempUn { get; set; }

    public ITemp TempDeux { get; set; }
}
```

This is not falling into the category "what I can do" but rather - quality design

And another user pointed out, you could return `IEnumrable<ITemp>` if number of objects was arbitrary. Or `List<ITemp>` if you needed to change number of items

Comment: Your examples are the bad old versions from before generics, LINQ, etc got introduced. They're still there for backwards compatibility but if you were building reflection and IO these days, you'd just build e.g. `EnumerateFiles` instead.

Comment: And while it's true that using an array to store two known elements is kind of weird, the OP was specifically concerned with whether the fixed storage space for an array element would prevent him from making an array of objects of different size.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Fine! I never though about it that way. I can agree. I could muster some other library, like one from Atalasoft or Izenda. However, in this case [I believe] it is still correct to say that - hey you don't have an arbitrary number of items. Are they going to specify `first element in return is **this** and second element is **that**` ?

Comment: @adv12 obviously, array on its own is an object and not a definition of object of N items. Any array with arbitrary number of items can "fit" into that object

Comment: @T.S. I'm not sure you understand what I'm getting at, or what the OP was getting at.  The OP has learned, probably from some other programming language, that all the elements in an array must take up the same space and seems confused by the fact that C# will let you make an array of an interface type and store objects of clearly different size.  The answer to the riddle is that only references to the objects are stored in the array, and the references to the two objects are of the same size.

Comment: @adv12 Ok. I've made a couple of additions